# What is a live wall paper and where is it located inside of the application file directory?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I am trying to include a live wall paper from another application inside my own application. This is a personal exercise to help me understand what kind of a file a live wall paper is and where to include it in my own application. Eventually, I would like to create and or customize my own live wall papers. I hope this question is clear enough.

edit: I found [this](http://chiralcode.com/android-live-wallpaper-template/) live wall-paper template that is a good starting point for newbies like me. It can be easily imported into eclipse. The template is available on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLiveWallpaper/article.html

Basically :

1.) create an XML file which describes your wallpaper

2.) create a service which must extend the WallpaperService class. This class is the base class for all live wallpapers in the system.

3.) use an Intent to set the Wallpaper

From a similar question on SO: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/108390/How-To-Create-Android-Live-Wallpaper